# Change list formatting in PyYAML output

Tags: formatting, python-3.x, pyyaml

This is how PyYAML behaves on my machine:

```
>>> plan = {'Business Plan': ['Collect Underpants', '?', 'Profit']}
>>> print(yaml.dump(plan))
Business Plan: [Collect Underpants, '?', Profit]
```

What I want instead is this output (both is valid YAML):

```
Business Plan:
- Collect Underpants
- '?'
- Profit
```

Is there some kind of option that would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the 'default_flow_style=False' argument to the call:

```
In [6]: print(yaml.dump(plan, default_flow_style=False))
Business Plan:
- Collect Underpants
- '?'
- Profit
```